# Customized virtual keyboard for Windows Store App

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, windows-store-apps

Since Microsoft doesn't allow to replace the system's virtual keyboard, I've developed a custom virtual keyboard as a `UserControl` to be used inside my Windows Store App. My current problem is that the default virtual keyboard always pops up whenever a user taps a `TextBox`.

I've been searching for a solution to this problem since yesterday, but I couldn't solve it. My almost successful attempt was developing a `TextBox` with a transparent `Canvas` over it. When the user taps the `Canvas`, the focus is programatically transferred to the `TextBox` and my custom virtual keyboard is instantiated. However, if no physical keyboard is connected to the tablet, the system keyboard also pops up with this approach (over my custom keyboard).

The main reason why I want to use a `TextBox` is because that way I can preserve and use the already implemented caret function, but it is not mandatory.

Any input will be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could do:

There are events for when the keyboard shows up, check those and see if you can prevent it.

You could implement a custom TextBox that suppresses OnPointerPressed event so that the TextBox is never focused. There are a couple of other things you'll need to do (such as prevent tabbing into it giving focus by setting `IsTabStop=false`.

You could implement a custom TextBox from the ground up (that looks and acts like a TextBox).

I think the second option is the easiest and most interesting option to try.

Edit: You could also give your TextBox a `DependencyProperty` that you set the current `Page` to via bindings. In the TextBox's `OnGotFocus` event, set the visual state to "CustomFocus" (or whatever you call it), then call `Page.Focus()`;

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Nate. Do you have any clue on how can I supress the OnFocused event? Thanks again.

Comment: I tried the second option as you suggested, but I don't know how can I suppress the event. RoutedEventArgs was supposed to have a Handled property, but it doesn't! When I try to set it, it says the property doesn't exist. And just overriding isn't enough:

protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. I've done some more research and it turns out that once the `OnGotFocus` event hits, it already has focus and it is too late. You need to intercept the `OnPointerPressed` event and set the `Handled` there. You can then create your own `VisualState` and transition to it (for things like doing Carat animations). Changing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You are right Nate: if the event is intercepted in OnPointerPressed the TextBox isn't focused and the soft keyboard doesn't pop up. However, since the TextBox doesn't have focus, the caret isn't displayed... I guess I'll try the other alternative you sugested: implementing a TextBox from the ground. How do you suggest I represent the caret? The only option I could think of is constantly displaying and hiding a character that looks like the caret.

Comment: I believe that's how they do it actually. You can do it with an animation that changes the opacity of the caret. If you use keyframes, you can have it auto-reverse and loop indefinitely (while in the 'CustomFocused' state).

Comment: Nate, I've implemented the Custom TextBox we've been talking about, although it is not perfect. Since the character that is similar to the caret takes some space (the caret doesn't), when the user places it in the middle of a word it becomes weird because it adds some space... Do you know if there is a way to solve this? Thanks again

Comment: I assume you are drawing it in a Stackpanel or possibly grid of some kind. You should draw it on *top* of the text, in a Grid. Whenever you tap on the Grid, it should find the position relative to the text and transform the caret. TextBox has a function `GetRectFromCharacterIndex` that should help with this.